# Set one attribute inside nested form before create it

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, has-many-through

I have a form with nested models, performances and locations. The nested is okey and create method okey. However, exists two attributes, rows and colums, both integers, inside of locations that build the matrix attribute in the same location model.

The method Loc(row,col) makes one array of hashs in the model that return the array with the columns and rows that i want inside matrix.

But i cant save the matrix because i do not know if i am acceding the right way to the params nested . any ideas?
    def new 
    if current_user
       @event = Event.new
       @event.build_clasification
       5.times do
       @performance = @event.performances.build
       8.times {@performance.locations.build}
     end
       else
         redirect_to new_user_session_path
     end
    end

```
def create
 if current_user
     @event = Event.new(events_params)
     @event.hourend = nil if params[:event]["hourend(4i)"].blank? && 
        params[:event]["hourend(5i)"].blank?
    params[:event][:performances_attributes].values.each do |item|
        item[:locations_attributes].values.each do |x|
          x[:matrix] = loc(x[:row].to_i,x[:columns].to_i)
        end
    end
    if @event.save
        redirect_to  events_path
     else
        rendirect_to 'events#new'
    end
  else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path, alert: "Debes iniciar sesión para ser promotor"
  end
end

  def loc(row,col)
    a = (0...col)
     c = Array.new(col){ Hash.new}
      a.each do |i|
      b = i.to_s(26).each_char.map {|i| ('A'..'Z').to_a[i.to_i(26)]}.join
      c[i] = {"fila" => b,"column" => (0...row).to_a}
      end
     return c
  end
```